# SqliteDatabase.getDatabaseName for API level 10

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the name of an opened database, for which I have a reference via a `SqliteOpenHelper`. No problem with API level 14 (`getDatabasename`). But I need it to work with API level 10 (hard requirement--this is for a class I'm taking).

The only idea I've come up with so far is storing the database name myself for future use--either in the class in which I need it or as a member of a subclass of `SqliteOpenHelper`. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDatabaseName()` returns the exact same name that you provided in the `SqliteOpenHelper` constructor, so the best is probably to store it in a member variable of a subclass. It will be more flexible if later you have another project where you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

but dont you already have the database name since your opening it and passing it to the constructor of SqliteOpenHelper ?  So just subclass SqliteOpenHelper and create the method getDatabaseName() yourself and let it do what you want.
 this seems to be more about object oriented principals.  Let me know if you need code or if im mistaken.

I grepped the code .  the function your looking for simply stores the variable you set in the constructor:

public String getDatabaseName() {
        return mName;
    }

so again make your own
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseName%28%29

Comment: I would prefer to keep my references to a SqliteOpenHelper--it creates more generic code. Looks like with old versions that isn't an option though.